# how do i append content of a dictionary to a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv') as csv_file:
    datarow = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=',')
    dict_places = {}
    list_places = []
    for row in datarow:
        dict_places['Continent'] = row[0]
        dict_places['Country'] = row[1]
        dict_places['Capital'] = row[2]
        print(list_places.append(dict_places))
```

I am reading  a csv file filename.csv , I am not  getting the desired result like below.

[{'Continent': 'Europe', 'Country': 'Spain', 'Capital': 'Madrid'}, {'Continent': 'Europe', 'Country': 'Portugal', 'Capital': 'Lisbon'}', {'Continent': 'Europe', 'Country': 'England', 'Capital': 'London'}]

Answer (score 1):

Move your declaration for `dict_places` inside the loop:

```
list_places = []
for row in datarow:
    dict_places = {}
    dict_places['Continent'] = row[0]
    dict_places['Country'] = row[1]
    dict_places['Capital'] = row[2]
    print(list_places.append(dict_places))
```

Otherwise you're just replacing the values in the same dictionary on each iteration and you'll end up with a list of the same dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) for this. It will do the hard work for you and make errors like this less likely. You just pass in the list of column names:

```
import csv
with open(path) as csvfile:
    rows = csv.DictReader(csvfile, ['Continent','Country', 'Capital'])
    list_places = [dict(row) for row in rows]

print(list_places)
```

prints:

```
[{'Continent': 'Europe', 'Country': 'Spain', 'Capital': 'Madrid'},
 {'Continent': 'Europe', 'Country': 'Portugal', 'Capital': 'Lisbon'}, 
 {'Continent': 'Europe', 'Country': 'England', 'Capital': 'London'}]
```

​